# Shift form-controls down when the tooltip placement is bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have form containing 3 inputs showing tooltips upon clicking the inputs. Added bootply below.

[bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/qxV2vNzjhI)

Because the tooltip text is large it is overlaying on the next form input. I want to shift the form controls down as the tooltip appears. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: That's fine. Any ideas to accomplish this will be appreciated.

Comment: I am looking for an answer or idea not leaving the code as is :)

Comment: This is really more of a UX question. You probably _shouldn't_ shift the other form controls around based on hover. Consider placing the tooltips to the left of the form controls where the eyes naturally focus when typing.